# Disabling notifications for the sender using apex toolkit

Tags: docusignapi, docusignconnect, docusignapextoolkit

I'd like to disable all sender notifications while using the apex toolkit. I disabled the notifications in the DocuSign account by unchecking all of the boxes, however, the sender is still receiving the notifications. I am assuming I need to add code to the apex class in order to disable these notifications. I don't see anything here (https://developers.docusign.com/docs/salesforce/apex-toolkit-reference/notifications.html) to help me with that, but I'm no developer so I could be overlooking it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't control another users notifications, only they can control the notifications that they're receiving by going into their settings and changing it there. If a user joins your account, they'll automatically inherit the notifications set at the account level, but it won't affect existing users.